# springboot-mongodb CRUD application

Tags: spring-boot

I have created a simple springboot and mongodb CRUD application for a user. I have setup the model,service,repository and controller for the user. The application starts all right but I am not getting any results when I invoke any CRUD operation.

```
2018-07-19 00:29:21.348[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21843[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
```

[2m2018-07-19 00:29:21.582[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21843[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@38234a38: startup date [Thu Jul 19 00:29:18 BST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
[2m2018-07-19 00:29:21.628[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21843[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/update]}" onto public java.lang.String com.airelogic.bugtrackersystem.controllers.UserController.update(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
[2m2018-07-19 00:29:21.629[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21843[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/delete]}" onto public java.lang.String com.airelogic.bugtrackersystem.controllers.UserController.delete(java.lang.String)
[2m2018-07-19 00:29:21.629[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21843[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/create]}" onto public java.lang.String com.airelogic.bugtrackersystem.controllers.UserController.create(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
[2m2018-07-19 00:29:21.630[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21843[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/deleteAll]}" onto public java.lang.String com.airelogic.bugtrackersystem.controllers.UserController.deleteAll()
[2m2018-07-19 00:29:21.630[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21843[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/get]}" onto public com.airelogic.bugtrackersystem.models.User com.airelogic.bugtrackersystem.controllers.UserController.getUser(java.lang.String)
[2m2018-07-19 00:29:21.630[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21843[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/getAll]}" onto public java.util.List com.airelogic.bugtrackersystem.controllers.UserController.getAll()
[2m2018-07-19 00:29:21.634[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21843[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
[2m2018-07-19 00:29:21.634[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21843[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
[2m2018-07-19 00:29:21.655[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21843[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
[2m2018-07-19 00:29:21.655[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21843[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
[2m2018-07-19 00:29:21.815[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21843[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
[2m2018-07-19 00:29:21.857[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21843[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port(s): 9090 (http) with context path ''
[2m2018-07-19 00:29:21.861[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m21843[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.a.b.BugtrackersystemApplication       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started BugtrackersystemApplication in 3.818 seconds (JVM running for 4.574)

When I invoke the getAll method it returns an empty list. Could someone help please?

The mongodb test db has the following data:

> db
>   test
>   db.user.find().pretty()
>   {
>       "_id" : 1,
>       "FirstName" : "Narasimha",
>       "LastName" : "Kotnala",
>       "UserName" : "nara",
>       "Password" : "kot"
>   }
>   {
>       "_id" : 2,
>       "FirstName" : "Rachel",
>       "LastName" : "Lintott",
>       "UserName" : "rach",
>       "Password" : "lin"
>   }
>   {
>       "_id" : 3,
>       "FirstName" : "Matthew",
>       "LastName" : "Stewart",
>       "UserName" : "matt",
>       "Password" : "ste"
>   }

Comment: You should rather share your code. Put it in a git repository and share it. That would help debug the issue.

Comment: I have uploaded to github. Please find the link.                                         https://github.com/NarasimhaRajuKotnala/bugtracker

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help. I was struggling with the same thing but this helped. In your main java file add @EnableMongoReposotries like below

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.test.testAPI"})
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages= {"com.test.testAPI.repository"})
```

I am making use of spring-boot 2.0.0 release